# d3 Line graph animation not consistent cross-browser

Tags: animation, cross-browser, d3.js, data-visualization, linear-interpolation

I am working on animating a line graph using d3.js, and have been closely following [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/duopixel/4063326). The code I have written works just like the example...but the bug I am trying to fix is one that is also unfixed in this example. (So going forward, just follow that link to see the bug for yourself)

In Chrome and IE10, the chart works just as it is supposed to. However, in Firefox, the line does not just draw itself from left to right. Instead, the page loads with the line already displayed, then the line *erases* itself from left to right, and then finally draws itself (again) from left to right like it should have done in the first place.

Also notice that the line drawing is twice as fast on firefox as the other browsers - this means that the issue is with the transition itself: the transition of the stroke-dashoffset property is handled differently by firefox and the other browsers. Specifically, if we remove the transition from the equation, the main difference becomes evident: With stroke-dashoffset set to totalLength, Firefox displays the entire path, as opposed to none of it, like the other browsers do.

So my question is: is this a bug, or is this bad form on my (and [duopixel](http://bl.ocks.org/duopixel)'s) part? If the former is the case, does anybody know a workaround or a fix? If the latter, I would be very grateful if you could show me the correct way to do this!

Comment: what version FF? I don't see this behavior on v22

Comment: 22 here too...if it isn't ff, what else could be causing it?

Comment: In that code there's a click handler for making it draw backwards. Is the click getting called somehow?

Comment: I saw that too...but that's not the case, because the draw backwards animation is different, and I left that out of my own code, but am still having the same issue